# ERR only (P)SUBSCRIBE / (P)UNSUBSCRIBE Laravel Echo

Tags: php, laravel, redis, laravel-echo

Good day!
I use PrecenseChannel and I catch join / leave on server side using a subscription to the Redis channel 
I use artisan command:

```
public function handle()
{
    $this->info("Presence channel watcher was started!");
    Redis::subscribe(['PresenceChannelUpdated'] , function ($message, $channel) {
        //Code for comparing users who leave and who join
        Notification::send($a1->users, new ExampleNotification($a2, $data));
    }
}
```

I use notification for send event (only broadcast)
But after sending Notification I get an error in console:

```
ERR only (P)SUBSCRIBE / (P)UNSUBSCRIBE / PING / QUIT allowed in this contex
```

Without notification, everything works and the notification itself works and sends broadcast

Since I use these notifications in the Services, therefore, the notification works

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Go to php.ini and set:

```
default_socket_timeout = -1
```

And add connection for Redis

```
Redis::connection('subscriber')->subscribe(['PresenceChannelUpdated'], callback)
```

Comment: I also have artisan command like below but no output printout. Does yours work?

public function handle()
  {
    Redis::subscribe(['PresenceChannelUpdated'], function ($message, $channel) {
      $this->info($message);
    });
  }

Comment: i have nice solution for detect user disconnection and connection via laravel PresenceChannelUpdated

Answer (score 1):

Once a Redis connection subscribes to a pubsub channel, it becomes a pubsub type connection that only allows (P)SUBSCRIBE / (P)UNSUBSCRIBE / PING / QUIT commands.

Looks like you are trying to use the same connection for other commands (R/W data possibly) which yields this exact error. The solution is to have two connections objects, one subscriber and one to deal with all other Redis commands.